# How do I prevent arrows from snapping when moving them on Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to create curved arrows with a custom angle/curve. I am using the "Directional Connector" from the Shapes list. It keeps connecting to the vertices of nearby shapes such as rectangles, images, etc., but I don't want that to happen. Also, I made sure the "Snap to Point" property is unchecked for that shape. What I can do to prevent it from snapping to vertices? Perhaps I'm using the wrong shape to create custom curved arrows?

Edit: I've also tried to use the "Curve" arrow shape but it still snaps to vertices of nearby objects.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To prevent snapping to points/objects try to press and hold **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** while you move the object/arrow.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. This does a "keep proportions" resize. 
`Alt` is the key I have to press and hold instead.
Drawio v 12.4.2 on Windows.

Comment: Same as @alelom, diagrams.net on Windows.

Comment: @user0 please reconsider updating your answer.

Comment: Both the 'Ctrl +Shift' as well as the 'Alt' is working for me.

Comment: CTRL SHFT copies the arrow

Answer (score 13):

My suggestion would be to start dragging a shape/arrow and then press and hold Alt.
That should "stop" the snapping regardless of the grid.

Comment: It's this, aka `Option` key on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find how to prevent arrows from snapping when moving them on Draw.io. However, I did manage to increase the granularity of the grid as shown [here](https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/editor-grid-change#:%7E:text=Show%2Fhide%20the%20editor%20grid,the%20size%20of%20the%20grid.) at Diagram/Grid on the right panel, and then move the vertex of an arrow while holding SHIFT, so that it sticks to the finer sub-grid of the main grid I got. That finer sub-grid gave me enough level of freedom to position my arrow's vertex.

Comment: To be clear are you saying that in your [example link](https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/editor-grid-change#:%7E:text=Show%2Fhide%20the%20editor%20grid,the%20size%20of%20the%20grid.) where it shows `Grid: 5pt` you increased that value such as to `10pt`?  Or did you decrease it?

Answer (score 1):

After the last update this is only achievable by disabling the grid altogether

Answer (score 0):

For people on MacOs Monterey (v12.3.1), try holding the `shift`  key while moving the shapes.